# Additional Static IP Address For Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Adding an extra static IP to an AWS instance is as simple as assigning a secondary private IPv4 address to a network interface and then assign the Elastic IP address to it.

We have customers hosting on the same machine that need additional IPs for the EV certificates or to meet PCI certification.

Please, how does one accomplish what ought to be a very simple task on Google Compute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create instances with [Multiple Network Interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces), up to a maximum of 8 network interfaces, each one can optionally have an external IP address.

Note that you can only configure a network interface when you create an instance and you cannot modify or delete the network interfaces after the VM has been created (You cannot delete a network interface without deleting the instance).

For internal IP addresses, you can use [Alias IP Addresses and Ranges](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/alias-ip).

Comment: Thanks, Neri.
I'm aware of this but the fact that each network interface configured in a single instance must be attached to a different VPC network, and each interface belonging to a different subnet will not work in our use case.
Not sure why the team behind GCP made most simple things static hostname, multiple IP, etc) practically impossible.
No wonder most business and engineers still prefer AWS.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may use forwarding rules as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963164/multiple-ip-addresses-on-a-single-google-compute-engine-instance). You can also open a feature request by filling this [form](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187134&template=1011214&pli=1). A good description of your scenario may help Google engineers to address this scenario in the future. Opening a feature request also gives other users the opportunity to vote for features that may be useful for them too.

Comment: Thanks, @ch_mike
I will open a request for the GCP team.