# How to host multiple domains in one instance in Google Cloud where each domain resolves to different ip address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to host 10 domains in once Google Cloud instance and each domain should resolve to different ip.

Can anyone here help me to achieve this,I could find a suitable solution so need your help guys.

Comment: This has been answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963164/multiple-ip-addresses-on-a-single-google-compute-engine-instance

Comment: For my previous comment make sure that you do a pricing review. Protocol forwarding is not cheap. Here is a Google article with step-by-step https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using forwarding rules.

What you will need is to reserve one static external IP addresses for each domain in your GCP project.
Then you will assign each static external IP address to a forwarding rule.

A forwarding rule object directs traffic that matches the IP protocol and port to a specified target instance. For more details, review the [forwarding rules](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rules) documentation.

The following commands will create a forwarding rule that forwards TCP traffic on port 80 to your target instance on the same port.
In your case as you have a static external IP address, you can associate it with the forwarding rule by specifying the --address IP-ADDRESS flag.

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create rule-name --ip-protocol TCP \
    --ports 80 --address IP ADDRESS --target-instance target-instance-name
```

This is fully documented on GCP public documentation at this link for [protocol forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding).