# Assigning multiple private-to-public mapping on a single GCE instance with a single NIC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is this setup possible in Google Cloud Platform? Because this setup is possible and easy to setup in Amazon Web Service.

[image: Click here to see the picture of the setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no way do exactly what you're asking in GCP.**

However there is a way to map multiple public IP's to a single VM instance using forwarding rules [which was discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963164/multiple-ip-addresses-on-a-single-google-compute-engine-instance).

To give you better understanding of GCP's networking have a loouk at how
you can create a VM with multiple interfaces (up to 8 per VM).

Also this documentation may be usefull - [how to create a VM with multiple NIC's](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces).

Last piece of documentation describes some [exaples and use cases with VM's and multiple NIC's](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/multiple-interfaces-concepts) which also may be helpful.