# GCP multiple STATIC IPs on the same VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to point 2 static ips (externals ips) to one VM.

My current configurations is as follows(I followed these steps: [Multiple IP addresses on a single Google Compute Engine instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963164/multiple-ip-addresses-on-a-single-google-compute-engine-instance) , or something like)

[image]

The IP A is configured directly on the VM.

The IP B is configured through forwarding rule.

The problem is that i have no response from IP B in any service / port (I tried it with telnet).

Ping to IP B is working:

[image]

1. Firewall rules are configured to allow http traffic on the VM (traffic is working through IP A in deed)
2. There is no "Load Balancing" configured, is just a target-instance & forwarding-rule.
3. I tried to make a "forwarding-rule" with specific port and also with all ports.
4. The VM has only one interface (nic0).
5. I'm not 100% sure if i can make it work only with one interface.

Does anyone know what could be going wrong on here?

Thanks.

---

I also tried it with a load balancer & frontend conf.:

[image]

But the problem is still there.

Do I need to manually configure routes / firewalls inside the VM ?

Firewall rules:

[image]

Comment: You need a load balancer and frontend configuration.

Comment: Ok. I'll try. But google documentation doesn't says something about that load balancer is required to use forward rules.

Comment: Did you configure firewall rules to allow the forwarded trafic? Implied rules block all ingress trafic. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls

Comment: I only set rules for incoming traffic. Give me a few minutes to check that link.

Comment: Ok. I didn't. Should i configure it from console? because I don't see any specific option for forwarding trafic  in https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list?

Comment: Yes, just click Create Firewall Rule at the top of the screen.

Comment: But the best way to have two eternal IPs for a VM is to attach it to two VPCs at the same time. Did you try this?

Comment: The problem with the VPCs is the limitation of VPc per VM. ( In a future, i will probably need more than 2 or 5 ip on the same VM), but if Load balancer does not work, i will try with VPCs.  BTW, I have created a firewall rule (Egress & Ingress), aply on all VM, and for any IP, but it dose not work (more details in the question).

Comment: @Karlkno I have replicated your environment and followed the provided tutorial to create a Target Instance and a Forwarding rule, and I can get to both IP Addresses, the only difference is that I'm running a simple HTTP Apache server. What service is your VM running?

Comment: Hi Gabriel. Thx for your time. I'm running Apache server over http, and another tcp aplications.  Did you have to create firewall rules?

Comment: @Karlkno no, the firewall rules are automatically created with the forwarding rule. If you don't see the rules created automatically, then a possible issue is with the [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setup-global-ext-https-compute#set_up_permissions).